# How to test RecyclerView in Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I've worked with Android for a while, but I'm fairly new to Test Driven Develeopment in Android.

I'm trying to test - when I type any text to the EditText, the RecyclerView shows some data from the server using the text I typed.

In real application, I'll receive data for the RecyclerView from the remote server. But how to test it, without any external resource?

I've found Mockito, which is mocking framework, and I know it provides ways to mock some external resources.. But when I stared to write some tests, I was so confused.. what should I do?? Should I use `mock(Database.class)` or something to mock the behavior of the Database?

Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/jamquery_list"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```